# GSON get for nested objects

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am struggling with some Gson and have not been able to find the answer to what I am looking for. Hopefully, I am not creating a duplicate.

Basically, I have a weapon class which has a sub-class of ammunition amongst others. However, not all weapons have ammunition, ie grenades.

My weapon class looks as followed:

```
public class Weapon_gson implements Serializable {

private ArrayList<String> Attachments, BuyFrom, Footer;
private String Description, MainImage, Name, Icon, Notes;

private Ammunition Ammunition;
private GeneralData GeneralData;
private Looting Looting;
private Performance Performance;

public Weapon_gson(ArrayList<String> attachments, ArrayList<String> buyFrom, ArrayList<String> footer, String description, String mainImage, String name, String icon, String notes, Weapon_gson.Ammunition ammunition, Weapon_gson.GeneralData generalData, Weapon_gson.Looting looting, Weapon_gson.Performance performance) {
    Attachments = attachments;
    BuyFrom = buyFrom;
    Footer = footer;
    Description = description;
    MainImage = mainImage;
    Name = name;
    Icon = icon;
    Notes = notes;

    Ammunition = ammunition;
    GeneralData = generalData;
    Looting = looting;
    Performance = performance;
}

private class Ammunition {
    ArrayList<String> AcceptedAmmunition;
    String Caliber, DefaultAmmo, DefaultMag, MuzzleVelocity;

}

public String getCaliber() {
    return Ammunition.Caliber;
}
```

}

and I use Gson to load the data

```
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<Weapon_gson>>(){}.getType();

    ArrayList<Weapon_gson> TempWeaponArray = new ArrayList<>();

    // Read file in stream mode
    try (JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(in)) {
        reader.beginArray();
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            // Read data into object model
            Weapon_gson weapon = gson.fromJson(reader, Weapon_gson.class);
            TempWeaponArray.add(weapon);
        }
    }
    return TempWeaponArray;
```

This returns the weapon objects correctly and I am able to get the caliber if the json data contains Ammunition.Caliber. However, if the json does not contain ammunition, Ammunition will be null and the call to the caliber fails.

**Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String uk.co.design2dev.escapefromtarkov.Weapons.Weapon_gson$Ammunition.Caliber' on a null object reference**

Looking in the debugger shows that Ammunition is null so I get why it's failing to get the caliber but I am just not sure how to best handle this?

Later on, when I use an adapter to populate the recyclerview, I want to hide the caliber textview if it is not available but I am not sure how to best achieve this.

```
    if(currentWeapon.getCaliber() == null){
        holder.weapon_calibler_tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else{
        holder.weapon_calibler_tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.weapon_calibler_tv.setText(currentWeapon.getCaliber());
    }
```

Also, do I even need the constructor if I work with Gson in this way?
Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your version of the Gson library?

Comment: I am not sure but I will check as soon as I get home. When I just read it again tho I a wondering if it could be related to my naming convention. Because I use "private Ammunition Ammunition" and in the getter I use Ammunition (which may try to access the class rather than the instance of the class)

Comment: The reason I ask about the version is because this was apparently an issue before, but have been fixed. Maybe you have the outdated version. As of the naming convention you should stick to camel case which is (as far as I know) best practice in Java. Maybe that's the problem!

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely check it. From the top of my head I'm struggling to recall where I even set it. I assume it's in the gradle?! Have been doing so much restructuring that I just can't recall, otherwise if I didn't specify anything I would not expect it to work. Will keep you posted tho!

Comment: Hey Viggo, I am using version 2.8.5 of Gson... And the naming also does not seem to be the issue. I have updated the names and it only made things worse... I'm totally at a loss here. Cheers

Comment: let’s try a different approach then. In your getCaliber(), perform a null check on Ammunition before trying to access Ammuntion.Caliber.

Comment: :) that's actually exactly what I have done and I'm just returning null if ammunition is already null. It works, but I was hoping there would be a smarter way, still feels like I'm missing something. Thanks for your comments and I think I'll leave this open in the hope someone might clear me up. Cheers